# Scrolling a UIScrollView to accommodate the keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a scrollview holding a content view 1500 pt tall.  The screen it's scrolling in is a standard iPad portrait screen (1024).

I have a number of textFields scattered about the scrollview's content view.  When I pop the keyboard open (by tapping on a textField) I am already bumping my scrollview's bottom constraint up by 216 points to make room for the keyboard.  However, if my text view is sitting in the bottom part of the screen, it's still hidden by the keyboard.

I want to scroll the scrollview programatically (and I know how with `[self.scrollview setContentOffset:CGMake...`) but I don't know how FAR to scroll it.  I've tried to calculate it using the textField's frame's y coordinate but I think I can only retrieve that value relative to the height of the content view...not it's actual position on-screen (as if I measured it externally to the iPad using a measuring tape with points as the unit).

In order to calculate how far to scroll the view I need to know where that text box sitting on-screen, right now--so I can figure out if it's going to get covered by the keyboard and shift the scroll by just enough to see it.

Any ideas how I can figure out where the textField is on-screen?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add screen shot in your question for more clarity

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_keyboard_covers_text_field

Comment: Use `convertRect:fromView`, `convertRect:ToView`, `convertPoint:ToView`, or `convertPoint:fromView` to translate coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code snippet for obtaining the same  result in my iPhone app. Find a suitable value for   ***heightDiff***

```
float heightDiff = 150;

CGPoint yScrollPoint = [self.scrollView convertPoint:CGPointZero fromView:self.textfield];
CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, yScrollPoint.y - heightDiff);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
```

Add this in your **textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField**

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Matt posted a link in a comment above with a full explanation of how to do this and more:  http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_keyboard_covers_text_field